# .Wait() causes TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, wait

I have a function that sends out an email, like so:

```
public async Task SendEmail(string from, string to, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHtml = false)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(host, port))
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.SendCompleted += SmtpOnSendCompleted;
                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
            }).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                LoggingService.Instance.BusinessLogger.Error(task.Exception.Flatten().InnerException);

            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
```

As you can see it is not a "true async", but rather a "deffered execution", so that I can call this method and it wouldn't block the current calling thread.

Now, I sometimes need a way to wait for the email to be sent, before proceeding. So I call my SendMail() method like so:

```
EmailService.Instance.SendEmail("from@blah.com", "to@blah.com", "Subject", "Body text").Wait();
```

with a .Wait() at the end.

For some reason using .Wait() - trying to force synchronous execution, cause exception:

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled

Questions:

1) Why am I getting this exception?

2) How do I force synchronous execution of this method?

Thanks

Comment: You got the exception because the task completed in the "Cancelled" state (`Wait()` didn't 'cause' this, it simply propagated that information).

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you take out the ContinueWith and use a try/catch? It's not clear why you would use ContinueWith here, but what might be happening is that the continuation task is cancelled because the primary task (from `Task.Run`) completed successfully.

Comment: Also, the `SendCompleted` event is only raised in conjunction with the `SendAsync` method. The synchronous Send method does not cause the event to be raised. Is there a reason to not use the task based method, `SendMailAsync`?

Comment: Why this question is down-voted heavily? It is valid and good!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1) Why am I getting this exception?**

You are getting the exception because,

- The **original Task** completed successfully without any faults
- You're having a **continuation** with **TaskContinuationOptions** set as **TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted**
- As there were no faults in the original Task's execution, you get a **AggregateException: A task was canceled.** because the continuation didn't execute and it was canceled

**2) How do I force synchronous execution of this method?**

You can force synchronous execution by,

- Using [Task.Wait Method (TimeSpan)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Using [Task.RunSynchronously Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321435(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g.

```
var task = new Task(() => { ... });
task.RunSynchronously();
```

Check how the below program behaves when you throw an error in the original Task and when the original Task completes without any faults by commenting/uncommenting the dummy exception. You can execute the below program at [http://rextester.com/](http://rextester.com/MFEIO79730)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DoSomething().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething completed");
        }

        public static async Task DoSomething()
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Doing Something");
                // throw new Exception("Something wen't wrong");
            }).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're only logging the exception when anything goes wrong using the **ContinueWith** method, then you can get rid of that **ContinueWith** and put a **try catch block** inside the original Task to catch any exceptions and log them.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSomething().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("DoSomething completed");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static async Task DoSomething()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Doing Something");
            throw new Exception("Something wen't wrong");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to do some additional work after original Task completes you can do it as follows.

```
namespace SO
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoSomething().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething completed");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task DoSomething()
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Doing Something");
                // throw new Exception("Something wen't wrong");
            }).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
                {
                    // log exception
                    Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
                }
                else if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                {
                    // do continuation work here
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Answer. I simply wrapped in a try-catch block. Even though I wish there was a way to not thrown the CancellationException when using ContinueWith() option.

Comment: Thanks, you can invoke ContinueWith method without TaskContinuationOptions such as OnlyOnFaulted to avoid the TaskCanceledException http://rextester.com/WHB97904

Comment: @Boriska64, do you want to know whether there is a way to use ContinueWith & TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted without getting a TaskCanceledException I think that it is the default behavior, please check TaskContinuationOptions Enumeration to know more about TaskContinuationOptions here at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, how long I have fought with a code similar to this. Like all emails are sent, but I still get this weird cancelled exceptions. Thanks a million.

Comment: @GhasanAl-Sakkaf I’m happy to help